# convert Text file 2D array to integer 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, text-files

I am trying to use data from text file (matrix [i, j]). I have code works with one dimension array  but doesn't work with two dimension array. I tried to use different method but I always get an error.

```
 string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(file path);
 string[] integerStrings = fileContent.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
 integers = new int[integerStrings.Length];
 for (int n = 0; n < integerStrings.Length; n++)
 integers[n] = int.Parse(integerStrings[n]);
```

I modify it to this

```
  string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(path);
        string[,] integerStrings = fileContent.Split(new char[,] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        integers = new int[integerStrings.Length,2];
        for (int n = 0; n < integerStrings.Length; n++)
            for (int j = 0; j <2; n++)
                integers[n,j] = int.Parse(integerStrings[n,j]);
```

the text file

```
0   0   
2   0   
4   0   
6   0   
8   1   
10  1   
12  1   
14  2   
16  3   
18  3
```

Note the code I need should be fixable with rows number

Comment: there is no invalid number

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What algorithm did you use and how the numbers are represented in your text?

Comment: one second let me type the code

Comment: How does your input file looks like?

Comment: Split method does not give you 2d array.... You have to show the format of your text... An example so we can help.

Comment: I modified the question

Comment: Use `File.ReadAllLines` to give you the numbers per line. and then split by space. each line is y and each token in the split will be x

Comment: Why not saving as 1,0 where 1 is X and 0 is Y, so save your file content as X,Y
And just split with ',' ?
The other is as Nkosi said. The size of the matrix rows is the size of the number of lines.
The number of columns is always 2.
Just split spaces for each ReadLine. Splitting spaces gives you this output: { X, Y }

Comment: thank you I will try this, if you can give me an example I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the lines from the file then split each line to get your 2d array. Here is a rough first draft. You can test and refactor to improve on it if needed.

```cs
int[,] matrix = null;
int rowCount = 0;
int colCount = 0;
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
rowCount = lines.Length;
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    var tokens = line.Split(new []{' ', '\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);        
    if(matrix == null) {
        colCount = tokens.Length;
        matrix = new int[rowCount, colCount];
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
        matrix[i, j] = int.Parse(tokens[j]);
    }
}
```

this part is for display the matrix

```cs
int rowLength = matrix.GetLength(0);
int colLength = matrix.Rank;

for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++) {
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", matrix[i, j]));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: File.ReadAllLines(path) give me an error I tried to use ReadAllTexts but will give me another error at the line split ..

Comment: still getting an error  `matrix[i, j] = int.Parse(tokens[j]);`         ` {"Input string was not in a correct format."}`

Comment: I just tested this exact code against your input from the example and got no errors. what did you change from what I provided? This works for int only based on your question so make sure that that you don't have any floating point numbers in your input

Comment: this is link to google drive you can download the txt file   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BypKQy6gqhpkLUthYjhoaE84YWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You sample file is separated with tabs. Made another edit to cater for the tab.

Comment: Yep tested with your sample file and by allowing for tabs fixed the problem

Comment: It works fine but the result are not two column matrix same as my txt file.. what I get is something like this  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BypKQy6gqhpkbW9fcGFPeDdSS0U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: result of what? All I showed was how to populate the 2d int array. you said nothing about displaying anything. and to add that now woudl be outside of the scope of what originally asked.

Comment: it works fine thank you ..I thought from the display it's one dimension array but after I test it, it give me what I want.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want 2d array split method just gives 1d array so you have to split twice...

First split by line breaks then by spaces...

```
string[] rows = fileContent.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

int[,] result = new int[rows.Length,2];

for(int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
{
     var col = rows[i].Split(new char{' ','\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

     result[i,0] = int.Parse(col[0]);
     result[i,1] = int.Parse(col[1]);
}
```

Comment: `col` would be a 1d array resulting from Split. But you are using it as a 2d array in the following lines.

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for that. Im posting with my phone and its hard to do without keyboard! ;)

Comment: still getting an error {"Input string was not in a correct format."}